# Granting Rights on Teradata Database that Contains " - " and " . " in its Name

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have a  teradata query  that is mentioned below

```
Grant Dump, restore, select on FAD-Data.Practice to Backup_1
```

It is giving me error that something expected between the word Fad and '-'

The database name is not correctly written but how can I make sure to grant rights from FAD-Data.practice to Backup_1 without changing database name. Also to mention that is sample code, I am using cursor to fetch database names and grant rights on it. I need a way that if the cursor fetches database name that contain database name like I have mentioned above so that it doesnot cause error and rights are granted on it

Let me elaborate it in further details
Lets say that the cursor fetched database name like

```
    For Rights_Grant as GETINDEX Cursor for
    sel database name from dbc.databases

Do
set DB_NAME=Rights_GRANT.DATABASENAME;
set SQL_TEXT='Grant Dump, restore, select on || DB_NAME || to Backup_1;';
```

If the cursor picks up database name like 'FAD-Data.Practice' it through an error. All want is that if cursor encounter name as mentioned above, it should execute

Comment: FAD minus Data... Try `"FAD-Data"` instead.

Comment: Its a database name. If I only write fad- then how I can grant rights on it . Basically, It is a cursor that is taking database name and dynamically assigning rights to it

Comment: Does delimiting with double quotes work?

Comment: I have tried that but it didnt worked

Comment: Just now I tried that it is giving me error that Fad-data doesnot exists

Comment: Now I understand, it's a database name, not a table name: `"FAD-Data.Practice"` Reading a question carefully helps:-)

Comment: Btw, in Standard SQL (and most DBMSes) a double quoted name is case-sensitive, but in Teradata it's still case-insensitive.

Comment: Yes, may be cast or convert helps me out